# SQL database rights

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

what can be wrong if a system/App is denied access to connect to the database in sql 2012? The error message that pops up is database is being used exclusively by another user.

Comment: Please show us the error

Answer (score 0):

try to execute this command from master db:

`ALTER DATABASE [your-database] SET MULTI_USER WITH rollback immediate`